# What export form is this called? export default name({...})(Class)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking at Reactjs code looking like this..

```js
export default authenticatedApplication ({

  // a very long code

})(App);
```

What form is this called? `export default name({...})(Class)` I don't even know what to Google.
The closest I could find is [this explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), but does not have the form of the code in question.

Comment: It's just a function call. `authenticatedApplication(...)` returns a function that is immediately called with `App`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any programming is about assembling pieces of a programming language to do what you want. You can't look at a large chuck of code and think "Oh this is *a* blank". You have to look at the pieces and how they work together.

So break it down:

- `authenticatedApplication` is a variable containing a function
- `authenticatedApplication({})` calls that function passing it an argument
- `authenticatedApplication({})(App)` takes the return value of calling that function (which must be another function) and calls it (passing it `App` as an argument)
- `export default authenticatedApplication({})()` takes the return value of that function and makes it the default export for the module

---

> The closest I could find is this explanation, but does not have the form of the code in question.

The MDN documentation *does* have that form:

```
export default expression;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

This code exports the function the return value of calling the return value of `authenticatedApplication`, called with `App`.

### More in-depth

`authenticatedApplication` is a function. The `({})` means a function call with the object passed as an argument.
Then `(App)` means you are immediately calling the return value of this function with the class `App`.